# Kinzie - Modify custom rom to enable VOLTE support

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, stock-rom, motorola

I'm a newbie to Android and Custom ROM in general. I was able to flash a workable custom rom (Android 7.0) on my Moto X Force by following steps from xda-developer.

So basically the device Moto X Force (release under the codename Kinzie, XT1580) in India does not support VOLTE. The same phone released in US (droid turbo 2, XT1585) supports VOLTE in contract with Verizon. I performed lot of search on google if there is a custom ROM which can enable the VOLTE support on this phone but couldn't find any.

What I have tried so far:

1. I managed to install various custom and stock ROMs on my phone.
2. Flashed Verizon stock ROM on my device but it did not detect the SIM card at all. I tried updating the radio from other custom ROMs but no luck.

Can someone please confirm if enablement of VOLTE is possible by software ? Looks like the phone has the required hardware to support VOLTE. If yes, then please point me in the right direction of achieving it.